# Jpanel does not show Drawing

Tags: java, jpanel, drawing, flicker

im new here and got a little problem with a JPanel and the draw Methods. I want to create a Gameboard unsing the GridLayout for each cell of the Game. Can be seen in the Code GridPainter.
Now i want to add at a random cell a circle and this should be shown on the gameboard.

THis is the method inside of my Controller. I Create a new Grid

```
    private void createBoard(int width, int height, int islands) {
        grid = new GridPainter(width, height, islands);

        bridges.getDraw().removeAll();
        bridges.getDraw().add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        
        bridges.getDraw().revalidate();
        bridges.getDraw().repaint();
        
        
    }
```

GridPainter
I Create a new Panel with a GridLayout and add to each cell e new JPanel as my gameboard. So Method paintComponente is only called if i use the Menubutton in my Game and the Menuview is shown.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridPainter extends JPanel{

    
    private int rows;
    
    private int cols;
    private int islands;
    
    private int originX = 1;
    private int originy = 1;
    private int cellSize = 45;
    private int cellSizeY;
    private DrawIslands dIslands;
    private Island island;
    private JPanel islandHolder[][];
    
    public GridPainter(int cols, int rows, int island) {
        this.islands = islands;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        islandHolder = new JPanel[cols][rows];
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(cols, rows, 1,1));
        for(int m = 0; m < cols; m++) {
            for(int n = 0; n < rows; n++) {
                islandHolder[m][n] = new JPanel();
                islandHolder[m][n].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                islandHolder[m][n].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                this.add(islandHolder[m][n]);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    //@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        createIslands(islandHolder[5][5].getGraphics());
        
    }
    
    public void drawIslands() {
        Random randomSize = new Random();
        int x = randomSize.nextInt((cols-1)+1);
        int y = randomSize.nextInt((rows-1)+1);
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        islandHolder[1][0].getGraphics();
        
    }

    public boolean hasIsland(JPanel panel) {
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the islandHolder
     */
    public JPanel[][] getIslandHolder() {
        return islandHolder;
    }

    /**
     * @param islandHolder the islandHolder to set
     */
    public void setIslandHolder(JPanel[][] islandHolder) {
        this.islandHolder = islandHolder;
    }

    
    
    public void createIslands(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(10, 10, 200, 200);
        //this.revalidate();
        //this.repaint();
        
    }

}
```

Can some of you guys can help me?

If i remove the revalidate() and repaint() methode inside of the function createIslands the graphic will be shown but its flicker.